# How can I pass data from a Recyclerview to another one?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a movie review app. I am trying to pass data from a Recyclerview to another recyclerview in a new activity. Currently I know how to pass data from Recyclerview to textview and imageview. However I looked online and also tried codes but still I could not pass data from recyclerview to recyclerview. What I am trying to pass is a String ArrayList that contains urls. How could I pass the data? Please help me TY! I just recently started on android studio

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .into(holder.image);

    holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked on an image: " + mNames.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MovieDetails.class);
            //v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MovieDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_url", mImageUrls.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("image_name", mNames.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("director_name", mDirector.get(position));
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("movieTrailer", mTrailer);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}

private void setImage(String imageUrl, String imageName, String directorName, ArrayList trailerUrl) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting the image and name to widgets.");

    TextView name = findViewById(R.id.text_movie_original_title);
    name.setText(imageName);

    ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image_movie_detail_poster);
    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(image);

    TextView director = findViewById(R.id.text_movie_director_name);
    director.setText(directorName);

    RecyclerView trailer = findViewById(R.id.movie_videos);
    trailer.set;
```

Comment: Is it possible to even pass data from recyclerview to another recyclerview? I want to get the intent in the new activity but I don't know how to do it. For a textview, i do String (variable name) = getIntent().getStringExtra(name) and i set it with TextView (variable name) = findviewbyid(R.id.textviewtitle); name.setText(variable name). How do i set text with a recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("urlList", list)
```

send it via `intent`

get arraylist by

```
getParcelableArrayList("urlList")
```

Comment: Do you know how i can set the url to a recyclerview, so that when it is clicked it will open the link in youtube?

Comment: post your adpater code form where you want to open new activity

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: which one is arraylist containing URLs? You want to pass everything in `mImageUrls` to new activity

Comment: the one containing the url is mTrailer

Comment: I added a code I have already how do i set a string to a recyclerview

Comment: If I understand it correct you want to set `string array list` to `recyclerview` in `new activity`

Answer (score 0):

i think these steps would help:
1. create arrays

2. put the same values to the arrays, you put on the recyclerView.
3. pass the arrays using intent. Example:

   ```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putStringArray("arrayOfName", new String[]{name1, name2});
   bundle.putStringArray("arrayOfImageUrls", new String[]{url1, url2});
   Intent intent=new Intent(context, SecondActivity.Class);
   intent.putExtras(bundle);
   ```
4. then in the second activity:

   ```
   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
   String[] names=bundle.getStringArray("arrayOfName");
   String[] urls=bundle.getStringArray("arrayOfImageUrls");
   ```
5. add this arrays to the recyclerView adapter in the SecondActivity
6. set the Adapter to your recyclerView